# Windows Phone: Custom Contact Store cannot edit contact name?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a WP8 app that creates a custom contact store, when I add some contacts programmatically  (by retrieving info from a server), and I go to the people's hub and modify the contacts names, the new names do not appear as the display name of the contact.

when I press edit contact again, I can see the new values, but still they don't appear as the display name for the contact.

what can be the reason for such a strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you different contacts linked together? In that case you see only the name of the main contact in the overview.